# javax RS: Check RESTful API peremeter

Tags: java, rest, parameter-passing, rx-java

I am new to java EEE. So many things to learn yet.

I have been developing a webservices where I have been using javax RS. I have created several RESTful endpoints some of them are requires expensive method call. So, I would like to validate the API perematers before further processing.

What are the possible frameworks for parameters? I heard about Jersey. Thank you in advance for help and suggestion.

I have been using JDK 7.

Comment: You can use JSR 303, its bean validation spec. Please check here https://dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-made-simple

Comment: You missed the link probably?

Comment: I updated my comment some time back. Please check. https://dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-made-simple

Comment: Thank you, I am gonne redirected to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to validate, Jersey has some tools to validate parameters as shown here [Bean Validation Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html).